# Silverlight 5 in-browser connect to socket

Tags: silverlight, sockets

I'm making a silverlight 5 in-browser app which will read and write from socket which is on server (192.168.1.92). I'm testing app on my development machine (192.168.1.10). I checked "Require eleveated trust when running in-browser" and it works. So I'm wirtting from 192.168.1.10 to socket on 192.168.1.92 and it works! But when I deploy app on web server on 192.168.1.92 and run app from my development machine (192.168.1.10) I get security exception "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.".

In [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570470/in-browser-trusted-application-silverlight-5/14119874#14119874) there is need for changing registry, but I don't want to change it because I want to run app from other machines too, and I don't want to change registry each time.

Is it possible to give app permissions without changing anything on client side?
And how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should certify your application.