# Silverlight 5 In browser trusted application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0, elevated-privileges

i am Working on Silverlight5 Application. We have to Open one Exe from Client Pc. As We try with In Browser Trusted Application and it's work within the Localhost but we try to using IP address instead of  Localhost then again application unable to open Exe.

We try to sign Application with Test Certificate and install in **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** And **Trusted Publisher**

Now it was working with Localhost as well as IP address but within a My Pc but Not working in Network Pc.

Please Suggest me, what things i am missing or what i have to do

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am got my question's answer, the problem with the test certificate,when i am using a actual certificate (from verisign) my application is working as per our expectation, it's open a exe from client machine.